# Geometry collections: sets or multisets?

Tags: ogc

In OGC, are collections of geometries equivalent to sets, or to multisets?

For example, is
((1.1, 1.1), (2.2, 2.2))
equivalent to or different from 
((1.1, 1.1), (1.1, 1.1), (2.2, 2.2))?